# Arduino +CCLK at command parsing

Tags: serial

I have arduino leonardo and sim800h module. I don't seem to find the problem in my program, this is probably the 5th time I'm rewriting it. Please someone tell me what should I change to work normally. I decodes the answers, but some chars seem to disappear and sometimes appear again. With time only +CCLK stays everything else is gone. Also the time should update all the time, but the seconds stay the same for 5-10 seconds.

This is the code:

```
const long interval = 200;
static long currentMillis;

byte searchcharpos = 0; //To determine where is the + in +CCLK in the char array

char serialdata[256]; //Array to store the chars before parsing

char rtcy1[3]; //Current year  Format: yy\0
char rtcm1[3]; //Current month  Format: mm\0
char rtcd1[3]; //Current day  Format: dd\0
char rtch1[3]; //Current hour  Format: hh\0
char rtcmm1[3]; //Current minute  Format: mm\0
char rtcs1[3]; //Current second  Format: ss\0

byte pointingfinger = 0;

char enabledtime = 0;

char readenabl = 0;

char foundchar[6];

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); //USB to Computer
  Serial1.begin(9600); //UART to Modem
  Serial1.print("ATE0\r"); //Disable echo
}

void loop() {
  if (millis() - currentMillis >= interval) //This is done every second
  {
    Serial1.print("AT+CCLK?\r");

    Serial.println("=========");
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 1]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 2]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 3]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 4]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 5]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 6]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 7]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 8]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 9]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 10]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 11]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 12]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 13]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 14]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 15]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 16]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 17]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 18]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 19]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 20]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 21]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 22]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 23]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 24]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 25]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 26]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 27]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 28]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 29]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 30]);
    Serial.print ("=========");
    //Serial1.print("AT+CCLK?\r"); //ask for the time
    //delay(50);
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("=====");
    Serial.println(millis());

    Serial.println("YEAR: ");
    Serial.print(rtcy1[0]);
    Serial.println(rtcy1[1]);
    Serial.println("MONTH: ");
    Serial.print(rtcm1[0]);
    Serial.println(rtcm1[1]);
    Serial.println("DAY: ");
    Serial.print(rtcd1[0]);
    Serial.println(rtcd1[1]);
    Serial.println("HOUR: ");
    Serial.print(rtch1[0]);
    Serial.println(rtch1[1]);
    Serial.println("MINUTE: ");
    Serial.print(rtcmm1[0]);
    Serial.println(rtcmm1[1]);
    Serial.println("SECOND: ");
    Serial.print(rtcs1[0]);
    Serial.println(rtcs1[1]);

    enabledtime = 1;

    currentMillis = millis();
  }

  if (enabledtime == 1) {
  if (Serial1.available () > 0) {
    if (foundchar[0] == '\n') {
      /*for (byte a = 0; a < 255; a = a + 1 ) {
        serialdata[a] = 0;
        }*/
        readenabl = 0;
      //pointingfinger = 0;
      enabledtime = 0;
      rtcy1[0] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 8]; //getting first char with its offset
    rtcy1[1] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 9];
    rtcy1[2] = '\0';
    rtcm1[0] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 11];
    rtcm1[1] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 12];
    rtcm1[2] = '\0';
    rtcd1[0] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 14];
    rtcd1[1] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 15];
    rtcd1[2] = '\0';
    rtch1[0] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 17];
    rtch1[1] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 18];
    rtch1[2] = '\0';
    rtcmm1[0] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 20];
    rtcmm1[1] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 21];
    rtcmm1[2] = '\0';
    rtcs1[0] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 23];
    rtcs1[1] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 24];
    rtcs1[2] = '\0';
    }

    if (foundchar[0] == '\r') {
      readenabl = 0;
      //pointingfinger = 0;
      enabledtime = 0;
      rtcy1[0] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 8]; //getting first char with its offset
    rtcy1[1] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 9];
    rtcy1[2] = '\0';
    rtcm1[0] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 11];
    rtcm1[1] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 12];
    rtcm1[2] = '\0';
    rtcd1[0] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 14];
    rtcd1[1] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 15];
    rtcd1[2] = '\0';
    rtch1[0] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 17];
    rtch1[1] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 18];
    rtch1[2] = '\0';
    rtcmm1[0] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 20];
    rtcmm1[1] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 21];
    rtcmm1[2] = '\0';
    rtcs1[0] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 23];
    rtcs1[1] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 24];
    rtcs1[2] = '\0';
    }
    foundchar[0] = foundchar[1];
    foundchar[1] = foundchar[2];
    foundchar[2] = foundchar[3];
    foundchar[3] = foundchar[4];
    foundchar[4] = foundchar[5];
    foundchar[5] = Serial1.read();

    if (foundchar[0] == '+' && foundchar[1] == 'C' && foundchar[2] == 'C' && foundchar[3] == 'L' && foundchar[4] == 'K') {
      readenabl = 1;
      pointingfinger = 0;
    }
    if (readenabl == 1) {
      serialdata[pointingfinger] = foundchar[0];
      serialdata[pointingfinger + 1] = 0;
      pointingfinger++;
    }
  }
  }
}
```

This is the output:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Try to reduce it to an absolute minimalistic example. Trigger the request once, then read all available characters repedeately. Try this sketch: https://pastebin.com/sRJy63Dt Do you get the full response?

Comment: Oh, I do see a fatal problem: The baud rate for `Serial` is the same as those of `Serial1`. Printing a debug stuff or whatever is extremely slow on `Serial`. Increase to at least 115200 baud on `Serial` so you can eliminate the possibility of waiting too long for serial writes.

Comment: I get full response, even if interval = 200. Now I need to search the + and copy with offsets all the parameters. But how? Increasing speed seemed logical, but in this case it didn't change much.

Comment: I think you should change your approach to reading and processing the serial data. After sending a request over Serial, you should spin in a loop until the end of the answer is received (double `\r\n` I think?). In that loop, just dump the received data into a buffer. After it was received completely, analyze the received response (split into year, month, day, et cetera). I think you are loosing to much time in your combined "read and process" method with a billion variable assignments before each read.

Comment: Can you give an example of a full response string? You might be able to just `sscanf` the integers out of there.

Comment: this is the output your program gives: `Sending request

+CCLK: "04/01/01,06:33:06+00"

OK` I was actually able to use the idea for the loop in my program and so far it's working fine now

Comment: If it's working you can maybe write up a full answer on the code and techniques used to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

This is the final working program that requests the time and parses the answer:

```
const long interval = 1000;
static long currentMillis;

byte searchcharpos = 0; //To determine where is the + in +CCLK in the char array

char serialdata[256]; //Array to store the chars before parsing

char rtcy1[3]; //Current year  Format: yy\0
char rtcm1[3]; //Current month  Format: mm\0
char rtcd1[3]; //Current day  Format: dd\0
char rtch1[3]; //Current hour  Format: hh\0
char rtcmm1[3]; //Current minute  Format: mm\0
char rtcs1[3]; //Current second  Format: ss\0

byte pointingfinger = 0; //index of the array

char enabledtime = 0; //this variable is set to 1 every second and set to 0 after parsing is done

char readenabl = 0; //this is set to 1 when is finished reading from serial

char foundchar[6]; //small buffer that works as a shift register to hold only the command for comparison

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); //USB to Computer
  Serial1.begin(9600); //UART to Modem
  Serial1.print("ATE0\r"); //Disable echo
}

void loop() {
  if (millis() - currentMillis >= interval) //This is done every second
  {
    Serial1.print("AT+CCLK?\r");

    Serial.println("=========");
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 1]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 2]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 3]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 4]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 5]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 6]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 7]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 8]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 9]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 10]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 11]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 12]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 13]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 14]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 15]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 16]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 17]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 18]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 19]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 20]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 21]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 22]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 23]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 24]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 25]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 26]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 27]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 28]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 29]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 30]);
    Serial.print ("=========");
    //Serial1.print("AT+CCLK?\r"); //ask for the time
    //delay(50);
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("=====");
    Serial.println(millis());

    Serial.println("YEAR: ");
    Serial.print(rtcy1[0]);
    Serial.println(rtcy1[1]);
    Serial.println("MONTH: ");
    Serial.print(rtcm1[0]);
    Serial.println(rtcm1[1]);
    Serial.println("DAY: ");
    Serial.print(rtcd1[0]);
    Serial.println(rtcd1[1]);
    Serial.println("HOUR: ");
    Serial.print(rtch1[0]);
    Serial.println(rtch1[1]);
    Serial.println("MINUTE: ");
    Serial.print(rtcmm1[0]);
    Serial.println(rtcmm1[1]);
    Serial.println("SECOND: ");
    Serial.print(rtcs1[0]);
    Serial.println(rtcs1[1]);

    enabledtime = 1;

    currentMillis = millis();
  }

  if (enabledtime == 1) {
    if (Serial1.available () > 0) {
      /*
        if (foundchar[0] == '\n') {
          readenabl = 0;
        //pointingfinger = 0;
        enabledtime = 0;
        rtcy1[0] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 8]; //getting first char with its offset
        rtcy1[1] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 9];
        rtcy1[2] = '\0';
        rtcm1[0] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 11];
        rtcm1[1] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 12];
        rtcm1[2] = '\0';
        rtcd1[0] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 14];
        rtcd1[1] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 15];
        rtcd1[2] = '\0';
        rtch1[0] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 17];
        rtch1[1] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 18];
        rtch1[2] = '\0';
        rtcmm1[0] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 20];
        rtcmm1[1] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 21];
        rtcmm1[2] = '\0';
        rtcs1[0] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 23];
        rtcs1[1] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 24];
        rtcs1[2] = '\0';
        }
        if (foundchar[0] == '\r') {
        readenabl = 0;
        //pointingfinger = 0;
        enabledtime = 0;
        rtcy1[0] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 8]; //getting first char with its offset
        rtcy1[1] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 9];
        rtcy1[2] = '\0';
        rtcm1[0] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 11];
        rtcm1[1] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 12];
        rtcm1[2] = '\0';
        rtcd1[0] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 14];
        rtcd1[1] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 15];
        rtcd1[2] = '\0';
        rtch1[0] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 17];
        rtch1[1] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 18];
        rtch1[2] = '\0';
        rtcmm1[0] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 20];
        rtcmm1[1] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 21];
        rtcmm1[2] = '\0';
        rtcs1[0] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 23];
        rtcs1[1] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 24];
        rtcs1[2] = '\0';
        }

        if (foundchar[0] == '\r') {
        readenabl = 0;
        //pointingfinger = 0;
        enabledtime = 0;
        rtcy1[0] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 8]; //getting first char with its offset
        rtcy1[1] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 9];
        rtcy1[2] = '\0';
        rtcm1[0] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 11];
        rtcm1[1] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 12];
        rtcm1[2] = '\0';
        rtcd1[0] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 14];
        rtcd1[1] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 15];
        rtcd1[2] = '\0';
        rtch1[0] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 17];
        rtch1[1] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 18];
        rtch1[2] = '\0';
        rtcmm1[0] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 20];
        rtcmm1[1] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 21];
        rtcmm1[2] = '\0';
        rtcs1[0] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 23];
        rtcs1[1] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 24];
        rtcs1[2] = '\0';
        }
      */
      foundchar[0] = foundchar[1];
      foundchar[1] = foundchar[2];
      foundchar[2] = foundchar[3];
      foundchar[3] = foundchar[4];
      foundchar[4] = foundchar[5];
      foundchar[5] = Serial1.read();

      if (foundchar[0] == '+' && foundchar[1] == 'C' && foundchar[2] == 'C' && foundchar[3] == 'L' && foundchar[4] == 'K' && foundchar[5] == ':') {
        readenabl = 1;
        pointingfinger = 0;
      }
      if (readenabl == 1) {
        while (foundchar[0] != '\n') {
          if (Serial1.available() > 0) {
            serialdata[pointingfinger] = foundchar[0];
            serialdata[pointingfinger + 1] = 0;
            pointingfinger++;
            foundchar[0] = foundchar[1];
            foundchar[1] = foundchar[2];
            foundchar[2] = foundchar[3];
            foundchar[3] = foundchar[4];
            foundchar[4] = foundchar[5];
            foundchar[5] = Serial1.read();

          }
        }
        readenabl = 0;
        //pointingfinger = 0;
        enabledtime = 0;
        rtcy1[0] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 8]; //getting first char with its offset
        rtcy1[1] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 9];
        rtcy1[2] = '\0';
        rtcm1[0] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 11];
        rtcm1[1] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 12];
        rtcm1[2] = '\0';
        rtcd1[0] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 14];
        rtcd1[1] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 15];
        rtcd1[2] = '\0';
        rtch1[0] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 17];
        rtch1[1] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 18];
        rtch1[2] = '\0';
        rtcmm1[0] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 20];
        rtcmm1[1] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 21];
        rtcmm1[2] = '\0';
        rtcs1[0] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 23];
        rtcs1[1] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 24];
        rtcs1[2] = '\0';
      }
    }
  }
}
```